# How do I build the current regulator circuit referred to on the LM337 datasheet?

Tags: current-source, constant-current, lm317, current-sink

**What I would like to accomplish:** I am trying to add current regulators into a home built dual rail linear regulated power supply.  I previously asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202059/where-how-should-i-fuse-this-transformer) about transformer fusing and received useful responses from the EE Community.  The supply is mostly complete now and I also added a current source using the following schematic off the [LM317 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf):

[image: Current Source using LM317]

I adjusted the resistor values though to ensure that the current source stays well below my max current (.35Amps on each secondary of the transformer).

I would like to also build a current regulator on the negative rail using either Figure 12 or Figure 15 from the [LM337 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm137.pdf):

[image: Example from LM337 Datasheet]
[image: Example from LM337 Datasheet]

**Problem:** I may not understand exactly what is going on with the LM337 schematics, but I cannot figure out how to connect this circuit up correctly, especially after the LM317 current regulator was straight forward.

Where do I place the load?  I think this is supposed to be a Current Source where the load goes between V-in and V--.  I appreciate any help you can provide in understanding how the LM337 current regulator configurations are supposed to work.

Comment: The LM317 circuit, after you put the resistor in, is just a two-terminal limiter.   It will work in series with a load regardless of whether the series connetion is (+)-load-regulator-(-) or (+)-regulator-load-(-), and regardless o f whether (+) or (-) is ground.  So, there's no reason to do an LM337 variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use them exactly as you used the 317, -ve supply input to Vin, load between ground and ADJ, resistor between ADJ and VOUT. As shown in the schematic below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgAy1s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They are shown the way they are shown in the data sheet because current flows from ground, out of Vin and into your -ve power supply pin - remember conventionally we say that current flows from +ve to -ve

Comment: I just tried placing the load between ADJ and Gnd and it worked.  To make sure I understand what's going on, is this current regulator operating as a current sink?

Comment: Yes (ish) that's not really a useful way of looking at it. The load and regulator components together are a current sink, the regulator (and associated resistor) is really acting as a variable resistance that will get higher when the current limit is reached.

Comment: @DaveG - but also note that you should not do this as an add-on current limiter for a voltage supply. Adding this circuit will cause very considerable voltage losses at the load. At the least, you have the drop across the resistor, plus the dropout voltage (~1.5 to 2 volts).

Comment: Thanks @WhatRoughBeast, definitely don't plan to make this a current limiting device, rather a way to control current regardless (for the most part) of voltage.